# Not able to Install AWS Toolkit in Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, eclipse-plugin, toolkit

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for eclipse on the eclipse Neaon 3 version 4.6.3. But get below errors..

Please anyone help me out.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.cloudformation_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.codecommit_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.codedeploy_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.codestar_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.core_2.3.1.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.dynamodb_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.ec2_1.1.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.identitymanagement_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.javasdk_1.11.248.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.opsworks_1.0.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.ui_2.1.0.v201807201743.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow_1.0.0.v201202211329.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**strong text**
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 12 releases and 4 years behind. Probably your Java is also retro and did not work with the certificates of nowadays.

Comment: i was checked with updated `eclipse-jee-2020-12-R-win32-x86_64` one also, but in that version not even showing anything after searching in available software for AWS Toolkit

Comment: See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/comment/7334#comment-7334